# What is the optimal index for this query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of bookings which I query in this way:

```
db.bookings.find({client: sessId, start: {$gte: weekStart}, end: {$lte: weekEnd}}).toArray(callback)
```

`start` and `end` are Dates, and so are `weekStart` and `WeekEnd`. I'm not sure about the optimal index for this query. It think it's something like this:

```
db.bookings.ensureIndex({client: 1, start: 1, end: -1})
```

or:

```
db.bookings.ensureIndex({client: 1, start: 1})
```

Thanks for help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the optimum would be

```
db.bookings.ensureIndex({client: 1, start: 1, end: 1})
```

as the ordering (ascending or descending) does not matter by searching for greather than or lesser than. You can search in both directions on both indexes. But I think it is a bit faster to add new data to the end of the index if it is ordered ascending and the new added dates are getting greater, too.

The most data set reducing attribute should be the first index. (This should be the normal case if you have a lot of clients and one client has just some dates).

Comment: "as the ordering (ascending or descending) does not matter by searching for greather than or lesser than" I must admit I am personally unsure about this, do you have a reference or working to show this? You cannot search in both directions on a compound index, only singular field indexes. Also in reality the date range might actually be more reducing than client_id in some cases, dependant upon true selectivity. Basically something which only he knows.

Comment: @Sammaye: I'm pretty sure client is the best way to narrow down the data in my app. At least for most cases. But good point!
Regarding the asc/desc question I'm unsure aswell! I do think order matter in a compound index.

Comment: But maybe asc or desc only matter if I want to *sort* the result. I my case the sorting does not matter. I just want to find all bookings during a week under a certain client and return all of them in one array.